# convert Bitmap to Mat after capture image using android camera

Tags: android, opencv, bitmap, mat

```
Mat b = new Mat();
Bitmap bmp = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("image_send");

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_image);
    Mat tmp = new Mat (bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
    Utils.bitmapToMat(bmp, tmp);
    Imgproc.cvtColor(tmp, tmp, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
    //Imgproc.cvtColor(tmp, tmp, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGB, 4);
    Utils.matToBitmap(tmp, bmp);

    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
}
```

Can't display the bmp. My app has stopped after taking a picture.

Comment: you can't use opencv code in onCreate (the native so's werent loaded yet)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

[`Utils.bitmapToMat`](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.9/org/opencv/android/Utils.html#bitmapToMat(Bitmap,%20org.opencv.core.Mat)) converts an Android Bitmap to an OpenCV Mat. It requires a bitmap of type `ARGB_8888` or `RGB_565`.

```
import org.opencv.android.Utils;

Mat mat = new Mat();    
Bitmap bmp32 = bmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
Utils.bitmapToMat(bmp32, mat);
```

Comment: What is the use of this line `Bitmap bmp32 = bmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);`? Why can't I just do `Utils.bitmapToMat(bmp, mat);`?

Comment: i'm really in need of help with this question, can you help me, please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61216402/how-to-improve-image-segmentation-using-the-watershed

Comment: I can answer the above question.  The bitmapToMat only accepts certain bitmap types.  This ensures it is ARGB_8888.  If it's the wrong format, you'll get garbage on your mat.

Answer (score 7):

`Mat tmp = new Mat (bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8UC1);`

OpenCV Mat constructor expects rows, cols pair instead of width, height as its arguments, invert them.

Try:

`Mat tmp = new Mat (bmp.getHeight(), bmp.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC1);`

Comment: Also the type is wrong, at the time of conversion the image is still in color+alpha (CV_8UC4)

Answer (score 0):

With `Camera2` this task is very fast, only you need config the `ImageReader` with `ImageFormat` on `YUV_420_888` and then proccess frames with `OpenCV` like this:

```
// You can read image with differents patterns for example grayscale:
Mat mGray(height, width, cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE, pFrameData);
```

A **complete implementation** in the next answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49331546/471690

Answer (score -1):

Same problem with my app. In the main activity, I had to render OpenCV utilizable.
(I am assuming your app threw a link error when Mat library was used).
All sample apps do this. Include this your in main activity.

```
 private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
        @Override
        public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
            switch (status) {
                case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
                {
                    Log.i("OpenCVManager setup", "OpenCV loaded successfully");
                  //Use openCV libraries after this  
                } break;
                default:
                {
                    super.onManagerConnected(status);
                } break;
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_9, this,
                mLoaderCallback);
    }
```