# Transfer Mat type image from one activity to other

Tags: android, android-activity, imageview

I want to display my image through imageview for which I need to send a Mat Type image from one activity to other. In first activity an image is browsed from phone and after doing certain processing on that image, the result image is stored back in the same folder as that of input image in the phone. Now I need to display that result image on the mobile screen on the click of a button. How can I do this?
Thanks!

Comment: [Convert Mat to Bitmap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13134682/convert-mat-to-bitmap-opencv-for-android) and  [Pass a Bitmap object from one activity to another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459524/how-can-i-pass-a-bitmap-object-from-one-activity-to-another)

Comment: @AnuraagBaishya:: one thing more, in imageview what should i give for android:src  ?? Because the image is generated during app run only and gets stored in phone.

Comment: You can set it to @drawable/default_ic

Comment: But I don't have anything in drawable folder. So, It's showing error. error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/default_ic').

Comment: In that case set it to @android:color/white (or color/transparent)