# How to convert BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 to bitmap

Tags: python, opencv, bitmap

I have checked this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13134682/convert-mat-to-bitmap-opencv-for-android) :

It seems like in java,just use:

```
Utils.matToBitmap(mRgba, bitmap);
```

Would someone please tell me how to do this in python?

**Update**
I actually want to combine wxwidget with open cv like this

```
class BaseImageView(wx.BoxSizer):
    def __init__(self, project, panel, fps=5):
        .......    
        #blow line will give error
        self.bmp = wx.BitmapFromBuffer(width, height, self.removeBG(frame))
        self.image = statbmp.GenStaticBitmap(panel, wx.ID_ANY, self.bmp)
        self.Add(self.image)
        .......

    def removeBG(self, origFrame): 
        return  cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2().apply(origFrame)
```

Comment: Why do you need a Bitmap in Python? However Bitmap is a Java object, and it is not bound to exist in python as well, In Python Bitmaps are generally multi-dimensional `numpy` arrays

Comment: @ZdaR，thanks,I want to combine wxwidget with opencv

Comment: And what is the datatype of image that wxwidget is expecting ?

Comment: @ZdaR,I added some demo code