# How can I convert Mat to Bitmap?(Run on linux ,not android)

Tags: java, linux, opencv, bitmap, mat

I'm using OpenCV read image to Mat with Java, then put image pixels to JNI, however, the JNI required to use Bitmap format

How can I convert Mat to Bitmap with Java? It should run on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried?

```
Bitmap bmp = null;
Mat tmp = new Mat (height, width, CvType.CV_8U, new Scalar(4));
try {
    //Imgproc.cvtColor(seedsImage, tmp, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2BGRA);
    Imgproc.cvtColor(seedsImage, tmp, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGBA, 4);
    bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(tmp.cols(), tmp.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Utils.matToBitmap(tmp, bmp);
}
catch (CvException e){Log.d("Exception",e.getMessage());}
```

from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13134682/convert-mat-to-bitmap-opencv-for-android)

Comment: this is for android, i need to run on linux